# Download files from the remote server using Pentaho transformation

Tags: file, download, pentaho, transformation, pentaho-spoon

is there any way to retrieve a file from a web server using FTP protocol without using "Get A FILE WITH FTP" JOB STEP. I can only use TRANSFORMATION in Pentaho. Any ideas.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547680/how-download-binary-files-with-pentaho/76009230#76009230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REST Client to do that in a transformation. I am doing the same thing in some of my transformations. You can GET the file content in the stream using REST Client and use a Text File Output to store the content in a file. File format will be your choice.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit. i'm fairly new to pentaho

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that?, i would appreciate it a lot

Comment: Can u explain the underlying working of this process

Comment: Here, is the file being retrieved over an FTP or an HTTP connection?

Comment: Is FTP mandatory to you? REST is the way to use HTTP, and it can do the thing you want very easily. If you only want to use FTP, then you have to make the use of the job executor, which will call a job.

Comment: Also can u tell me how u are using this REST CLIENT to retrieve the file i.e., what all kinds of parameters u r putting in the REST CLIENT CONFIGURATION WINDOW so that it is retrieving the file to a TEXT FILE OUTPUT

Comment: Use Add Constant Step and define you url in the value, then connect REST, and check "Accept url from field". HTTP method will be GET, select the appropriate "Application type" and type the result field name whatever you want (e.g. result). Now join the Text File Output and add the result field in this step. Run the transformation.

Comment: Can u specify the Format for the URL i.e., can u give me an example?

Comment: Please elaborate about using the REST CLIENT. I'm still not being to retrieve the file. If u can please depict an  example for my better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can only use a transformation, a transformation can call a job using the "Job Executor" step.  You can do the FTP in the job you are calling.

A note of caution - you've got to explicitly check the output of the Job Executor Step for errors.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea too. But, he said he can't use job and job executor is going to call a job, even if it is inside a transformation.

Comment: Can u please explain how to do that? i'm fairly new to pentaho.